# Return selected values on change and not repeat on un-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, dropdown

How to always return selected options in an array. On change return new array of selected elements.

```
let yo = [];
$(`#filter`).on('change', function() {
   $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
        // console.log(this.value);
        yo.push(this.value);
   });
});
console.log(yo);
```

Right now this returns:

on first select my result is: `['one']`. 
On 2nd select, I get: `['one', 'two']`.
On `two` unselect, my result is `['one', 'two', 'one']`.
On `two` unselected how can I make my result be `['one']`?

On every change, can I just get back the selected elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to reset the `yo` array inside the function. At the moment, the array is only declared once, and then you keep pushing to it.

```js
$(`#filter`).on('change', function() {
   yo = [];
   $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
        // console.log(this.value);
        yo.push(this.value);
   });
});
```

This should work proerly, every time the on change function runs, it will reset the array before pushing to it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
$(`#select`).on("change", function(e) {
  //$(this).val() will get an array of selected values
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```